# Azure storage table entries deletion

Tags: azure-devops, azure-table-storage

I have some existing data in Azure table storage.So when I deploy csv file ,the latest changes are deploying but the data which is existed in the azure table storage is not overwriting or old data is not deleting.for ex:I have 3 rows of data in azure storage existing,when I deploy csv file which is having 5 rows,the5 rows data is deploying and old data of 3 rows is not deleting.It should be overwrite but its not happening.Please help me. –       Subscription Details:

```
$subscriptionName = "Tech Enabled Solutions"
        $resourceGroupName = "abc"
        $storageAccountName = "defghi"
        $location = "North Central US"
        $tableName = "TestTable"
        # Get the storage key for the storage account
        $storageAccountKey = "12345678990"
    # Get a storage context
        $ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction Ignore
        #If the table exists, start deleting its entities.
        if ($table -ne $null) 
        {
         $table=Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll -table $table | Remove-AzureStorageTableRow -table $table -Context $ctx
        }
```

Comment: Error for the above script:  2017-10-17T13:11:33.6495612Z ##[error]Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll : The term 'Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\deleteentity.ps1:20 char:11
  $table=Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll -table $table | Remove-AzureSto ...+   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound(GetAzureStorageTableRowAll:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll command is in AzureRmStorageTable Module, so install it before call command.

Add this command to your script to install that module:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module -Name AzureRmStorageTable -Force -Verbose -Scope CurrentUser
```

Comment: Awesome Bro.Really appreciating again.It worked now.Now,I can able to deploy one csv file data but if I want to deploy multiples csv files at a time then how can I perform through script.

Comment: My assumption is like,if I can pass files as a parameters in the script and it will read that file and can insert and delete the data for that particular file into azure storage.but the thing is currently I am inserting data using this command in the power shell script...$csv = Import-CSV "d:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\TestTable.csv" currently as per the script it is testtable.csv

Comment: if I want to pass different file say like testtable2.csv to the powershell script,I can't write 2nd script and keep in VSTS repo right as there are many csv files I need to deploy into azure storage.so at the run time of script how can I pass different files using one script which i am currently running. how can I implement the script and how can I pass parameters.

Comment: One more doubt pal, how can I deploy multiple  csv files into table storage as each csv file data is different in rows and columns and will have extra rows and extra columns for each csv file.So how can I automate/implement/change the above script for deploying multiple csv files using power shell script as not every csv file having same columns right,some may csv files have 3 fields and some csv files have 5,6,7 and so on filelds..I hope you understand my requirement.Please help me out.

Comment: Thanks Pal..I will open the new thread for this.Thanks for your continuous support.